# placing invisible links at certain coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, links, coordinates

Does anybody know if this is possible using TikZ?

I'm trying to create links over a picture that i have layed on the background of a frame or at least placing them on some nodes in a TikZ code.

Comment: Can you include a MWE for that frame only?

Comment: How do include the picture though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You can use the `\hyperlink`, `\hypertarget` mechanism provided by `hyperref` together with some TikZ `\node`s. In the following example, the `\invlink` command receives three mandatory arguments:

```
\invlink{<xshift>}{<yshift>}{<name>}
```

where the lengths `<xshift>` and `<yshift>` allow you to specify the horizontal and vertical shifting from the `(current page.center)` node, and `<name>` is the string that will be used for linking to the corresponding target. To have a large area for the links, I used a `\phantom` rule. Both the image and the links will be placed in the `background canvas`; in my example I used the frame titles for the `\hypertarget`s, but you can use any other element.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\invlink[3]{%
  \node at ([xshift=#1,yshift=#2]current page.center) 
  {\hyperlink{#3}{\phantom{\rule{1cm}{10pt}}}};
}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
  \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth,keepaspectratio]{ctanlion}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\invlink{0pt}{0pt}{A}
\invlink{60pt}{60pt}{B}
\invlink{-60pt}{-60pt}{C}
\end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{frame}
Some test text
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\hypertarget{A}{Test frame A}}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\hypertarget{B}{Test frame B}}
test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\hypertarget{C}{Test frame C}}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: is there any way to make the links temporarily visible?

Comment: @user28552 use some "real" contents for the second argument of \hyperlink.